# How to create a drawing with shadows and colors with muliple faces using d3js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

For my client, i have created a drawing using a 3d approach. here is the live :

http://plnkr.co/edit/8fDkcEwpCsx0bi1f467b?p=preview

and the code i used is :

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    var salesData=[
    {label:"Basic", color:"#e9d600"},
    {label:"Plus", color:"#DC3912"},
    {label:"Lite", color:"#1fc2c7"}
];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",700).attr("height",300);

svg.append("g").attr("id","salesDonut");


Donut3D.draw("salesDonut", randomData(), 350, 150, 130, 100, 50, 0.4);


function randomData(){
    return salesData.map(function(d){ 
        return {label:d.label, value:1000*Math.random(), color:d.color};});
};


})
```

it works fine. But my client asking to make a graph like this :

[image: the image like the graph need]

how to create like this? What is this chart type call as? I don't have any idea to make this.

any one expertised with d3js, can you please help me to reproducing the basic level or showing a tutorial or giving me a guide?

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking for something like this http://bl.ocks.org/supereggbert/aff58196188816576af0

Comment: Yes, but i am not require the animation. but still I don't have any idea to reproduce a map as like my image. it has 3 sides with 3 shadow faces and different directions